# Syncing GMail Calendar with the Calendar App in 2022

Tags: calendar

Is it actually possable to sync a Gmail calendar with the Elementary Calendar app??

I have searched hi and low for a solution and **nothing** works. Some posts online semed to accomplished this with previous versions of Chrome/Elementary. I using Elementary 6.1 and adjusting google settings in Chrome Version 103.0.5060.53.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Para el correo y el calendario debes utilizar las contraseñas obtenidas para cada aplicación desde la administración de contraseñas obtenidas de la cuenta de Gmail. Solo copia y pega la contraseña que te dan (es una con 16 letras) en el momento que el correo y el calendario te pida la contraseña de la cuenta que utilices. Esto se debe a los cambios de politicas de google para apps de terceros que dio inició hace unos meses. Saludos.